# To replace a number with strings in an XML file using a Perl script

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have an XML file. I need to replace the digits in comment="18" with comment="my string" where my string is from my @array ($array[18] = my string).

```
 <rule ccType="inst" comment="18" domain="icc" entityName="thens"  entityType="toggle" excTime="1605163966" name="exclude" reviewer="hpanjali" user="1" vscope="default"></rule>
```

This is what I have tried.

```
while (my $line = <FH>) {
      chomp $line;
      $line =~ s/comment="(\d+)"/comment="$values[$1]"/ig;
      #print "$line \n";
      print FH1 $line, "\n";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $fn = 'test.xml';
my @array = map { "string$_" } 0..20;
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $fn);
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//rule')) {
    my $idx = $node->getAttribute('comment');
    $node->setAttribute('comment', $array[$idx]);
}
print $doc->toString();
```

Comment: Thanks. I am no expert in perl. I know simple perl. I have tried this while (my $line = <FH>) {
      chomp $line;
      $line =~ s/comment="(\d+)"/comment="$values[$1]"/ig;
    #  print "$line \n";
      print FH1 $line, "\n";

}  and thought that there might be efficient ways to do this with XML perl module hence I have asked this question. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) example. It's basically the same idea as the [XML::LibXML example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65989383/2766176) done in a different way with a different tool:

```
use XML::Twig;

my $xml =
qq(<rule ccType="inst" comment="18"></rule>);

my @array;
$array[18] = 'my string';

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        rule => \&update_comment,
        },
    );
$twig->parse( $xml );
$twig->print;

sub update_comment {
    my( $t, $e ) = @_;
    my $n = $e->{att}{comment};
    $e->set_att( comment => $array[$n] );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am no expert in perl. I know simple perl. I have tried this while (my $line = <FH>) {
      chomp $line;
      $line =~ s/comment="(\d+)"/comment="$values[$1]"/ig;
    #  print "$line \n";
      print FH1 $line, "\n";

}  and thought that there might be efficient ways to do this with XML perl module hence I have asked this question. Thanks a lot for your answer.